# Hosting pure angularjs app on google app engine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have an angular js app with following structure 
[app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xzMA.png)

my app folder look like

[app folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRfrY.png)

the app does use any back end interaction for now but in future its gonna interact with a separate app engine java project . I want to host this angularjs app to google app engine but I am not able to understand the right configuration . I am more confused how do I set up the app.yaml for google app engine ... and is it necessary to have a main.py file as at present I do not have any handler

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you would like to host a static web page on app engine, specifically an AngularJS app.

You don't need any server side code and can configure your `app.yaml` as follows:

```
 runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
 - url: /
   static_files: www/index.html
   upload: www/index.html

 - url: /(.*)
   static_files: www/\1
   upload: www/(.*)
```

This is assuming you will host your client side code in a `www` folder and you use a `index.html` as your index file.

Also take a look at the following guide for hosting a static website [0].

[0] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website

Comment: Thanks . In future I may use some service from other app engine hosted java projects but I do nt think that should affect my current structure at UI end . I am keeping the UI and server as two separate project both hosted on app engine